# Adding count of children per parent in single data frame and count of all descendants

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Have a table of employees (key emp id) with one column being the boss (same key format). I was able to build out the hierarchy by doing repeated joins (took 10 for my real organization), but now I need to add a column for:

- employee_count (count of rows with the boss_id = emp_id of current row)
- empire_count (count of rows with the hierarchy starting the same way)

I'm most comfortable in the Tidyverse, here's some simplified fake data of what I have so far as example:

```
library(tidyverse)

employees = tibble(
  emp_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  emp_name = c('BigBoss','MedBoss','MedBoss2','Emp1','Emp2','Emp3','Emp4'),
  boss_name = c('','BigBoss','BigBoss','MedBoss','MedBoss','MedBoss2','MedBoss2'),
  hierarchy = c('','BigBoss','BigBoss','BigBoss>MedBoss','BigBoss>MedBoss','BigBoss>MedBoss2','BigBoss>MedBoss2')
)
```

Which looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  emp_id emp_name boss_name  hierarchy         
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>             
1      1 BigBoss  ""         ""                
2      2 MedBoss  "Bigboss"  "BigBoss"         
3      3 MedBoss2 "BigBoss"  "BigBoss"         
4      4 Emp1     "MedBoss"  "BigBoss>MedBoss" 
5      5 Emp2     "MedBoss"  "BigBoss>MedBoss" 
6      6 Emp3     "MedBoss2" "BigBoss>MedBoss2"
7      7 Emp4     "MedBoss2" "BigBoss>MedBoss2"
```

As far as what I'm looking for, `employee_count` should be 2 for each of the MedBosses and BigBoss, and then the `empire_count` for BigBoss would be 6.

For the `employee_count` piece, I could separately do a:

```
data %>% group_by(boss_name) %>% summarize(employee_count=n(emp_id))
```

and then join it back, but then the hierarchy wouldn't work the same way... I think the answer is some map function from purrr or creating a function, and Vectorize()'ing it and calling within a mutate, but that hasn't worked for me.

This is as close as I can get...

```
# Function to get the count of employees for a boss_name
get_employee_count = function(table,bossname) table %>% filter(boss_name==bossname) %>% nrow()

# This call works (returns 2)
get_employee_count(employees,'BigBoss')

# Try to add the count in via a mutate (returns 7 for each)
employees %>% 
  mutate(employee_count=get_employee_count(.,boss_name))
```

If I can get that to work, I think I could figure out the harder piece as I could do it also as a function.

Comment: Seems like it should be a tree, and I'll have to head scratch on that, but node edge.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I can do it if I hard-code the dataframe name, which is close enough for me.

```
# This is the solution
employees %>% 
  mutate(employee_count = map_int(emp_name,function(name) employees %>% filter(boss_name==name) %>% nrow())) %>% 
  mutate(empire_count = map_int(emp_name,function(name) employees %>% filter(str_detect(hierarchy,name)) %>% nrow()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a graph/tree problem. For employee count, just find all the adjacent nodes. For empire_count, enumerate all the simple paths and count the unique nodes. All easy enough with `igraph`

```r
library(igraph)

empTree <- graph_from_data_frame(
  employees |> 
    filter(boss_name != "") |> 
    select(from = emp_name, to = boss_name)
)

Count_Empire <- function(node) {
  
  paths <- all_simple_paths(empTree, node, mode = "in") 
  
  if(length(paths) == 0) return(0)
  
  ct <- paths |> 
    map(~as.vector(.x)) |> 
    reduce(c) |> 
    unique() |> 
    length()
  
  # minus 1 for self 
  ct - 1
}

Count_Employees <- function(node) {
  
  adjacent_vertices(empTree, node, mode = "in")[[1]] |> 
    as.vector() |> 
    length()
}

employees |> 
  mutate(
    employee_count = map_dbl(emp_name, Count_Employees),
    empire_count = map_dbl(emp_name, Count_Empire)
  )
```